# Assign a variable's value to what's returned from a JS function

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have a function that returns an object, like this:

```
function getJSON(url) {
    request.get({
        url: url,
        json: true,
        headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
    }, (err, res, response) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
        } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        } else {
            // JSON received successfully
            return response;
        }
    });
}
```

The function is working fine, but when I declare a variable to use what the function returns, it is `undefined` instead. I expect it to be an object.

```
var someVar = someFunction('url-to-the-json');
```

Comment: how does the object look like

Comment: By chance, Does the function do something asynchronous like call an api?

Comment: Is your function doing some `async` operation ?

Comment: Please share whole code to help you.

Comment: What is `anObject`? Does `// do something here` possibly contain a `return` statement with no value?

Comment: Minimal examples are fine, preferred in fact… but this is a bit *too* minimalistic.

Comment: You are doing it the right way but you may be doing async operations (like an ajax request) in your function causing it to reach `return` before the end of your requests or you may have context problems.

Comment: Top linked question in the [tag:javascript] tag… http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/476

Answer (score -1):

Try assign function to variable:

```js
var myVar = function someFunction() {
    //do something here
};
//then use myVar
function newFunction(myVar){
  //do something
 }
```

Comment: I'm puzzled by this. You are passing a function to a function? What does this have to do with the OP's question? What do you think accounts for the problem he is reporting?